# Close a Jquery modal using load()

Tags: jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

I've made a modal dialog used load() method but now I don't know how to close it.

The `button` and `div`:

```
<a href="#" id="btnAdd">Add</a>

<div id="AddModal" style="display:none"></div>
```

Script to call the modal:

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {
    $("#AddModal").load("/Customer/Modal/AddCustomerModal.aspx").show();
});
```

`AddCustomerModal` loaded inside the `AddModal`:

```
<body>
    <div id="AddModalContent">
        <h3>MODAL</h3>

        XYZ<br />
        <input type="button" class="btnCloseModal" value="Close" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Script to close

```
$(".btnCloseModal").click(function () {
        $("#AddModal").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `.btnCloseModal` doesn't exist before you load it's content into your page, so you can't really attach the `click` event to this element (yet).

The solution is to attach the `click` event to the `#AddModal` element, and check for the `.btnCloseModal` element inside:

```
$("#AddModal").on('click', '.btnCloseModal', function () {
    $("#AddModal").hide();
});
```